# Find if the contents of a string is in a word chosen randomly from list?

Tags: python

Can someone possibly tell me what to do with this bit of code?
It always comes back **True**:

```
def find_letter(letter, lst): 
    return any(letter in wordChosen 
               for wordChosen in attempt)

attempt = input("Enter the letter you think is in the word")
find_letter(attempt, wordChosen)
print find_letter(attempt, wordChosen)`
```

Comment: You need to define `find_letter` that does what you want it to.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.

Comment: I've done that, here:

Comment: `def find_letter(letter, lst):
    return any(letter in wordChosen for wordChosen in attempt)`

Comment: No, you have not done that.  Your code is in two different venues and does not execute cleanly.

Comment: How would I fix that?

Comment: Edit your original posting.  Post code that runs cleanly and exhibits the problem you have.  In short, what the documentation says.

Comment: ... or wait until I'm done ... I think I just fixed the problem ...

Comment: @Prune don't you think it has a certain constructive quality to it if we try to teach askers how to ask minimally answerable questions?

Comment: It does.  I was having fun with the convoluted learning, and he did get close.  Sometimes I teach by example, and you do have a point -- too much example on my part this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What's wrong**

You don't quite have the idea of the nice command you wrote.

```
for wordChosen in attempt
```

iterates your variable **wordChosen** through every character of the input.  The original value is now destroyed.

```
letter in wordChosen
```

checks just what you think.  However, since you passed in **attempt** as the value of **letter**, this *must* match.  Filling in "chosen" for wordChosen and "q" for the attempt, your code is now

```
find_letter("q", "chosen")
# and the code in the call looks like this:
any(letter in str for str in "q")
```

This will dutifully take every character in "q" and see whether that character is in the string "q".  :-)

Also, please note that you have a useless line of code:

```
find_letter(attempt, wordChosen)
```

calls the function and then ignores the return value.
The following line is fine; the **print** uses the value.
Keep that one and delete the useless one.

**The Solution**

```
# find_letter is simple:
def find_letter(letter, lst):
    return letter in lst

# Test program
wordChosen = "many_different_letters"
for attempt in "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm":
    print attempt, find_letter(attempt, wordChosen)
```

Output:

```
q False
w False
e True
r True
t True
y True
u False
i True
o False
p False
a True
s True
d True
f True
g False
h False
j False
k False
l True
z False
x False
c False
v False
b False
n True
m True
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I need the code to check the single letter answer inside of a string, and not for the letters to all be printed at the same time. I just want the code to return saying the letter entered is in the word randomly chosen or not.

Comment: Checking all the letters is merely a test case for the central logic I gave you.  I assume that you can extract the parts you need and work them into your code.